# what is this value means 1.845E-07 in excel?

Tags: excel, scientific-notation

I am reading the excel sheet from C# by using interop services. My sheet has one of cell value as 0.00. but run time when I am checking the value of that cell in C# code I am getting "1.845E-07" this value. When I check in excel sheet, on that cell right clicked , say format cell I got "1.845E-07" value in sample section. How to get exact value?
Please help me. The code is huge, so I can't provide it here.
 that line is:

```
if (Convert.ToString(((Excel.Range)worksheet.Cells[iRowindex, colIndex_q10]).Value2) != string.Empty)
{
    drRow[dtSourceEXLData.Columns[constants.Floor]] = ((Excel.Range)worksheet.Cells[iRowindex, colIndex_q10]).Value2.ToString();
}
```

Same problem with Date cells "39448". what does this means??please help....

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1.84E-07 is the exact value, represented using [scientific notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation), also known as exponential notation.

1.845E-07 is the same as 0.0000001845. Excel will display a number very close to 0 as 0, unless you modify the formatting of the cell to display more decimals.

C# however will get the actual value from the cell. The ToString method use the e-notation when converting small numbers to a string.

You can specify a format string if you don't want to use the e-notation.

Comment: but how to specify it string?? steps please.

Comment: well done ... now
   object testval = ((Excel.Range)worksheet.Cells[iRowindex, colIndex_q10]).Value2;
                    double dbl1 = Convert.ToDouble(testval);
                    //if (Convert.ToString(((Excel.Range)worksheet.Cells[iRowindex, colIndex_q10]).Value2) != string.Empty)
                    if (testval != null && testval != string.Empty)
                    {
                        drRow[dtSourceEXLData.Columns[constants.Floor]] = dbl1.ToString("F");//((Excel.Range)worksheet.Cells[iRowindex, colIndex_q10]).Value2.ToString();
                    }

Answer (score 1):

Highlight the cells, format cells, select Custom then select zero.